# Django: Sort Items in Dropdown (via field_order?)

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I am using a dropdown on a template. I do want an alphabetical order in that dropdown and don't know how to get this.

**template.html**:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset>
        {{ form|crispy }}
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The context comes from **views.py**:

```
def my_view(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            …

    return render(request, 'xxx/template.html', {'form': form})
```

The form is defined in **forms.py**:

```
from django import forms

from .models import Project


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    project = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Project.objects)
    field_order = ['name', ]
```

**models.py**:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    …
```

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.field_order) talks about `field_order`. The line `field_order = ['name', ]` in form.py has no effect.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documentation states this is ordering of form fields

for example of:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    project = forms.somefield
    name = forms.somefield
    field_order = ['name', ]
```

would show name prior to project in form

---

What you want is change sort order of `ModelChoiceField` that means you should change your queryset argument

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(Project.objects.order_by('name'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order them by changing your query to

`queryset=Project.objects.order_by("name")` 
or if you need reverse order `...order_by("-name")`.